Linux CentOS7 having issue in php source code install
After Linux finish ./configure
enter image description here
and i proceed to make. This happened.

/root/php-8.3.7/main/php_reentrancy.h:98:7: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__extension__’
   98 | char *strtok_r(char *s, const char *delim, char **last);
      |       ^~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:993: ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.lo] Error 1


Please give me some suggestion and strictly use source code to install php.
what i have tried.

redownload the source tar.gz
using older version but same problem

Result of running ./config.status
creating main/internal_functions.c
creating main/internal_functions_cli.c
config.status: creating main/build-defs.h
config.status: creating scripts/phpize
config.status: creating scripts/man1/phpize.1
config.status: creating scripts/php-config
config.status: creating scripts/man1/php-config.1
config.status: creating sapi/cli/php.1
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/php-fpm.conf
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/www.conf
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/php-fpm.service
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/php-fpm.8
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/status.html
config.status: creating sapi/phpdbg/phpdbg.1
config.status: creating sapi/cgi/php-cgi.1
config.status: creating ext/phar/phar.1
config.status: creating ext/phar/phar.phar.1
config.status: creating main/php_config.h
config.status: main/php_config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing default commands

+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| License:                                                           |
| This software is subject to the PHP License, available in this     |
| distribution in the file LICENSE. By continuing this installation  |
| process, you are bound by the terms of this license agreement.     |
| If you do not agree with the terms of this license, you must abort |
| the installation process at this point.                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+

Thank you for using PHP.

if I try to run a file to test this function.
gcc -o test_string test_string.c
./test_string
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "Hello, world!";
    char *token;
    char *rest = str;

    while ((token = strtok_r(rest, " ", &rest))) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
    }

    return 0;
}

Its working, and give a proper output.
This is the php_reentrancy.h file
#ifndef PHP_REENTRANCY_H
#define PHP_REENTRANCY_H
#include "php.h"

#include <sys/types.h>
#ifdef HAVE_DIRENT_H
#include <dirent.h>
#endif
#include <time.h>

/* currently, PHP does not check for these functions, but assumes
   that they are available on all systems. */

#define HAVE_LOCALTIME 1
#define HAVE_GMTIME 1
#define HAVE_ASCTIME 1
#define HAVE_CTIME 1

#if defined(PHP_IRIX_TIME_R)
#undef HAVE_ASCTIME_R
#undef HAVE_CTIME_R
#endif

#if defined(PHP_HPUX_TIME_R)
#undef HAVE_LOCALTIME_R
#undef HAVE_ASCTIME_R
#undef HAVE_CTIME_R
#undef HAVE_GMTIME_R
#endif

BEGIN_EXTERN_C()

#if !defined(HAVE_LOCALTIME_R) && defined(HAVE_LOCALTIME)
#define PHP_NEED_REENTRANCY 1
PHPAPI struct tm *php_localtime_r(const time_t *const timep, struct tm *p_tm);
#else
#define php_localtime_r localtime_r
#ifdef MISSING_LOCALTIME_R_DECL
struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *const timep, struct tm *p_tm);
#endif
#endif


#if !defined(HAVE_CTIME_R) && defined(HAVE_CTIME)
#define PHP_NEED_REENTRANCY 1
PHPAPI char *php_ctime_r(const time_t *clock, char *buf);
#else
#define php_ctime_r ctime_r
#ifdef MISSING_CTIME_R_DECL
char *ctime_r(const time_t *clock, char *buf);
#endif
#endif


#if !defined(HAVE_ASCTIME_R) && defined(HAVE_ASCTIME)
#define PHP_NEED_REENTRANCY 1
PHPAPI char *php_asctime_r(const struct tm *tm, char *buf);
#else
#define php_asctime_r asctime_r
#ifdef MISSING_ASCTIME_R_DECL
char *asctime_r(const struct tm *tm, char *buf);
#endif
#endif


#if !defined(HAVE_GMTIME_R) && defined(HAVE_GMTIME)
#define PHP_NEED_REENTRANCY 1
PHPAPI struct tm *php_gmtime_r(const time_t *const timep, struct tm *p_tm);
#else
#define php_gmtime_r gmtime_r
#ifdef MISSING_GMTIME_R_DECL
struct tm *php_gmtime_r(const time_t *const timep, struct tm *p_tm);
#endif
#endif

#if !defined(HAVE_STRTOK_R)
PHPAPI char *php_strtok_r(char *s, const char *delim, char **last);
#else
#define php_strtok_r strtok_r
#ifdef MISSING_STRTOK_R_DECL
char *strtok_r(char *s, const char *delim, char **last);
#endif
#endif

END_EXTERN_C()

#if !defined(ZTS)
#undef PHP_NEED_REENTRANCY
#endif

#if defined(PHP_NEED_REENTRANCY)
void reentrancy_startup(void);
void reentrancy_shutdown(void);
#else
#define reentrancy_startup()
#define reentrancy_shutdown()
#endif

#endif



You need to check your building environment and the config.status file. The error indicates that the configure script couldn't find strtok_r which usually should not happen. The config.status file may tell you what is wrong.

CentOS 7 is going end of life end of next month, I would find another distro

@shingo Thanks for your tips. I have solved this issue. The main problem is because I didnt completely solved the dependencies of some library (like GCC, I installed it by source code, but now I use yum to install devtoolset-11. Then can install PHP.
